# Console doesn't display result

Tags: java, file, console

I'm writing some code to get the latest file from a directory but the console doesn't display any result.

Here's the code I've written :

```
import java.io.File;

public class test {
    
    public static File getLastModified(String directoryFilePath)
    {
        File directory = new File("C:\\New folder");
        File[] files = directory.listFiles(File::isFile);
        long lastModifiedTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;
        File chosenFile = null;

        if (files != null)
        {
            for (File file : files)
            {
                if (file.lastModified() > lastModifiedTime)
                {
                    chosenFile = file;
                    lastModifiedTime = file.lastModified();
                    System.out.println(file);
                }
            }
        }

        return chosenFile;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {}

    
}
```

Comment: You already tried to print a string and not a object? Maybe, the part inside the `if` just isn't executed?

Comment: Who do you think is calling the `getLastModified` method? Your `main` method looks quite empty...

Comment: @John_H_Smith in that code, i tried using system.print and nothing shows either. I assume that the if statement may not be executed , i'll try again! Thanks for the response.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes i just realized that i was not calling the method. Thanks for pointing it out !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do 2 things,.

1. Need to call  getLastModified() method in your main method
2. Scanner reading each line in the file and doing system. print calls? while (scanner.hasNextLine()) { System.out.println(blah blah blah); }

Simple. Done!

Comment: oh i see , now it makes sense ! thank you

Comment: also , if i may ask , if i wanted to get the full dirPath of the file and assign it to an object as a string value , is it possible? Do brief me on this :D